# Is there a more British way to talk about tackling problems?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, british-english, idiom-requests, sports

I can see that the [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) is [at least aware](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tackle) of the use of *tackle* meaning "come to grips with a problem" and I can see that the [*Sunday Times*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tackle-the-problem) has used it on occasion. It still seems so connected to (American) football that it shouldn't be the most idiomatic way for a Brit to express the idea.

Is there any better or more common way to express this idea in British English? or do Brits just use the exact same phrasing but whilst imagining rugby or (field) hockey instead?

Comment: You tackle in rugby and association football. But the word is far older than organised sport https://www.etymonline.com/word/tackle

Comment: @StuartF And the older meaning is involved with ship's rigging and later fishing gear and has nothing to do with getting to grips with a problem. That said, it seems your source suggests that its use for grappling came from kitting out a horse and using that gear to keep it in line... Weird.

Comment: There's surely some kind of connection between getting to grips with a problem and the much older noun for a "device for grasping and shifting or moving", even if the verb is 19th century.

Comment: @WeatherVane Certainly. Is that a more natural expression in British English where Americans would say tackling it? From what you said above, it seems like you don't imagine any particularly vigorous exertion with tackling problems so maybe it seems identical to solving it (?).

Comment: Don't the Brits also say to **address** a problem? Maybe that's an option. [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tackle+a+problem%2C+address+a+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctackle%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caddress%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0) shows it preference over **tackle a problem** in British English.

Comment: I don't see anything 'un-British' about the word!!

Comment: @KateBunting I was going to say that... I agree.

Comment: Which particular sport is referred to as **football**? The question implies that we don't play football in Britain. The sport by that name played in America is more like what we know as *rugby football*.

Comment: What @fev said. Brits (and probably all other native Anglophones) use metaphoric (oratorial) ***address*** as well as (competitive) ***tackle*** and (haptic) ***get to grips with*** to describe the process of ***dealing with*** problems. I'm not sure exactly what kind of metaphor ***deal*** is in this context, but I doubt it alludes to playing cards (just as ***tackle*** doesn't really allude to ball games, or indeed dealing with the rigging on sailing ships! :)

Comment: **To the closer(s)**: There may be some policy this question is violating or another that it duplicates, but it isn't the one listed. There are plenty of sources that can be used to document British usage, as fev already did above. Just because some editors here have only given their opinions doesn't make it opinion based; it just makes their replies less authoritative.

Comment: @fev Those two are not in the same register.

Comment: @lly surely the main problem with the question is that it's based on the idea that Americans think of American football when using the expression *tackle a problem*, when it seems that's just you. Also, since the word *tackle* has no particular connection with American football as opposed to any other tackling sport (I mean it's not a term like 3rd base or whatever that's closely connected to a specific sport) there's no reason to think it would be out of place in any country where that kind of sport was played, even if everybody was like you in understanding it as a sports metaphor.

Comment: I don't think anyone has said it yet (apologies if I've missed it), but: football (of the "association" variety) is quite popular in the UK(!). Tackling happens in that sport too. So under the (questionable) assumption that the usage is football related, there need be no issue from that point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @tchrist pointed out, "***address*** a problem" is more formal than ***tackle***. And in fact, the Americans seem to use it slightly more commonly than the Brits, at least according to this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=address%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%2Caddress%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caddress%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caddress%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0). So I wouldn't say this is a particularly British expression.

However, my instinct was that actually the most British way to express this was ***tackle*** itself. I tried a wild card NGram and if you look carefully (BrE hits are blue and AmE hits are red), you will see that ***tackle the problem*** is the most common expression with this sense:

[image]

The most common verbs are ***be***, ***solve*** and ***resolve***, so ***tackle*** comes comes in fourth. And as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tackle%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%2Ctackle%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctackle%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctackle%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0) Americans also use it, but less. The next verb used with a meaning close to the one you are looking for is also ***[face the problem](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=face%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cface%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cface%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cface%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0)***, but it is "less physical" in connotation.

So the conclusion is that ***to tackle a problem*** is actually the most idiomatic phrase used in the UK for that meaning.

Now, it is not clear from your question if you are looking for a synonym phrase that will have the meaning of ***dealing with the problem*** but keep the somewhat dynamic connotation of ***tackle***, yet without the football allusion,<sup>1</sup> like the example you gave, ***come to grips with a problem***. If that is not the case, what follows may be irrelevant.

The verb ***grapple*** is quite physical but has no allusion to any sport. It means:

> 1. *to come to grips with* (one or more persons), especially to struggle in hand-to-hand combat
> 2. (intransitive; foll by with)
>
> - to cope or contend to grapple with a financial problem<sup>2</sup>

Another definition I found is:

> (*grapple with something*) *to try hard to understand a difficult idea or to solve a difficult problem*
>
> - The government continued;  e.g. to grapple with the issue of public transport.<sup>3</sup>

The expression to ***[grapple with a problem](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grapple%20with%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cgrapple%20with%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrapple%20with%20the%20problem%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrapple%20with%20the%20problem%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0)*** is used on both sides of the ocean, though the Brits do have "the upper hand" on it. However, it doesn't come anywhere near ***tackle*** as regards common use. Plus, ***grapple*** has this extra connotation that you are dealing with something difficult, sometimes annoyingly difficult, whereas ***tackle*** is more neutral towards the problem. It just expresses the dynamic energy with which you deal with a problem, whether difficult or not.

<sup><sup>1</sup>  I really think that Brits don't think about football every time they say ***We need to tackle this problem***.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grapple)</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grapple-with)</sup>

Comment: I'd associate grapple with proper wrestling and would've assumed that the image was rugby based (soccer tackling being an entirely different beast) but, as discussed above, it's all apparently originally involved with ships' rigging and controlling horses. In any case, thank you very much for tackling this and summing everything up so neatly!

Comment: Since @Lambie is interested below, [the *OED* entry for 'tackle'](https://oed.com/view/Entry/196938) does link the word most closely to its sense in wrestling, although oddly connecting its earliest use for wrestling grips most closely to 1820s New England slang but the source of its use for confronting obstacles and problems to the British writers Charles Dickens and Edward FitzGerald.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the English language (and many others for that matter) is that words expand their meanings by being applied figuratively to different situations. The native speaker uses the context of the word to interpret its meaning without confusion.

In the case of “tackle” no British person would be confused by the fact that it is an everyday word to deal with a problem, and an everyday word to describe an action in several team games (although *American* football would be unlikely to come to mind any more than [*Aussie-rules* football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_rules_football)).

The ngram of @fev confirms my feeling that *tackle* is most commonly used word in everyday speech, and alternatives like “address” are regarded as academic or unnatural, as several have commented.

I find it difficult to follow the logic of the statement that:

> “It still seems so connected to (American) football that it shouldn't
> be the most idiomatic way for a Brit to express the idea.”

Why should a Briton be aware of or be concerned about a mental association of the word in different culture, even assuming awareness of it? No more than a German should (or would) be concerned about the copulatory associations an English speaker might have with the German word for ‘fox’ or the bowel sounds the former might associate with exit signs on the Autobahn.

Of course, it is helpful if the individual travelling between countries is aware of the situation. There is no problem in Britain if a student says to another student “Lend me your rubber.” However if he spends a year in the US he needs to learn to say “Lend me your eraser.” Two countries divided by a common language.